# converting blob data into image using php

Tags: javascript, php, image, blob

I have a page in which I'm uploading an image using from input type=file to an image tag using this code

```
$('#profile-image-upload').change( function(event) {
var path = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);

$("#image").attr('src',URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]));
```

This gives me an bolb data of path like this blob:http://localhost:8080/467d02c9-0af0-448a-a239-69e8d4037dd1. My image is in this blob data saved in path variable

Now I also want this image file to save in my server directory and I'm use ajax to send it to my server

```
var ajax;

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)  // For modren Browsers
      ajax=new XMLHttpRequest();

    else
      ajax=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); // For IE5 & IE8

      ajax.open("POST","../UploadImg.php",true);

      ajax.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
     var data=  "path="+path+"&type="+user+"&id="+id+"&extent="+extent;


     //path = blob data       
     //user = user name
     //id = user id
     //extent = extension of image

      ajax.onreadystatechange=function()
      {
        if (ajax.readyState==4 && ajax.status==200){
            alert(ajax.responseText);
        }
      }

     ajax.send(data);

});
```

and my server side coding is

```
$img_ff = $_POST["path"]; // blob path
$user = $_POST["type"];
$id = $_POST["id"];
$extension = $_POST["extent"];

$dst_img= $user.$id.".".$extention;  // for example user17.png
$dst_path= "localhost:8080/live4others/images/";

$dst_cpl = $dst_path . $dst_img;   

if(move_uploaded_file($dst_cpl, $img_ff)){
        echo "yes";
    }else{
        echo "error";
    }

    if( file_put_contents( $img_ff, $dst_cpl)){
        echo "yes";
    }else{
        echo "error";
    }
```

both of the methods are not working. Please tell me where I'm doing wrong. They give error and says given path is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. I'm using same but using **blob** to simply preview the images/videos before submitting.

**Jquery**

```
$('#<formId>').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: "../UploadImg.php",
        type: "POST",
        data:  new FormData(this),
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        processData:false,
        success: function(response){
            console.log(response);
        }, 
        error : function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        }
    });
});
```

**PHP - UploadImg.php**

```
$tmpFile  = $_FILES['<fileElementName>'];

$absolutePathOfdestinationFolder = '/var/www/<projectDocRoot>/images/'.$user.$id.".".$extention;

if(move_uploaded_file($tmpFile['tmp_name'], $absolutePathOfdestinationFolder)){
    echo "yes";
}else{
    echo "error";
}
```

Comment: I'm having error of "Parseerror" in textstatus and in errorThrown  Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0(…).

Comment: $_FILES['<fileElementName>']; is not saving blob data in $tmpFile and gives error of "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$tmpFile' (T_VARIABLE)"